# Testing non-activity android applications

Tags: android, android-testing, android-monkey

Monkey is used to test applications with activities. Is there a way to make automated tests like monkey for non-activity applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, [you use JUnit for that](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html).

Also, bear in mind that nearly every application needs an activity, if you want the application to be usable on Android 3.1+. The exception might be some sort of plugin to some other app.

Comment: Thanks but the package is not mine. I am just testing an apk. Also there are too much apks.

Comment: @RicardoCristianRamirez: You would use JUnit for that too. You can create a JUnit test project that is marked to test "itself", meaning that Android will not try to automatically load some other project when it runs your tests. Your test code can then use the `ContentProvider` or bound service or whatever it is you think that you are going to test of this other APK.